# How to show the data of File objects using Expression Language?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I have an `ArrayList<File>` object which contains files. I have set the object to a parameter titled `"content"` as well as a `test` `String`:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("test", "test");
request.getSession().setAttribute("contents", contents);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

On the `jsp` page I am using the following to print out their values:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="15px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Filename</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${contents}" var="currentFile">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${currentFile.shortName}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<%= session.getAttribute("test") %>
```

However, the only thing being printed out is `test` even though `contents` definitely is populated with files.

How do I print the absolute filepaths of the `File` objects in the `contents` `ArrayList` on `index.jsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
<td><c:out value="${currentFile.canonicalPath}"/></td>
```

If `contents` is, indeed, a `List` of `File`.

Also, there's no specific reason to populate the `Session`, via the `request.getSession()`. You can place your data directly in to the request as an attribute using `request.setAttribute(...)`.

For truly transient data just for the JSP, this is a better place. Putting things in the Session has scope beyond the current request. (If that's intentional, no big deal, just an FYI.)